# Property of object not being recognized in switch cases

Tags: javascript, object, types, switch-statement

I have a

function that takes an object as input. This objects always looks like:

```
{
title: "Gesso:",
categorical: "",
text: "",
classe: "Conduta",
type: 3
}
```

All the objects I take as input have this property numerical 'type'. Depending on it, I build another object that is the function's output. As an example:

if type=1  -> I return {letter:input.a}
if type=2  -> I return {letter:input.b}

For this conditions I am using a switch statement as below (this is the function I'm having trouble with):

```
   resposta(answer){
        let toReturn;
        switch(answer.type) {
            case 1:
                toReturn = {
                    resposta:answer.text,
                    obs: ''
                    };
                break;
            case 2:
                toReturn = {
                    resposta:answer.categorical,
                    obs: ''
                    };
                break;
            case 3:
                toReturn = {
                    resposta:answer.categorical,
                    obs:answer.text
                    };
                break;
            default:
                toReturn = {
                        resposta:'',
                        obs:''
                        };
                break;
            };

        return toReturn;
    };
```

I already inspected the objects being passed and all of them have all the properties in the code, including answer.type.

When I:
`console.log(answer.type === 1 || answer.type ===2 || answer.type ===3)` I get `true` in all of the objects.

But, for some reason, the function always returns the default case, no matter which answer object I pass into it.

```js
function resposta(answer) {
  let toReturn;
  switch (answer.type) {
    case 1:
      toReturn = {
        resposta: answer.text,
        obs: ''
      };
      break;
    case 2:
      toReturn = {
        resposta: answer.categorical,
        obs: ''
      };
      break;
    case 3:
      toReturn = {
        resposta: answer.categorical,
        obs: answer.text
      };
      break;
    default:
      toReturn = {
        resposta: '',
        obs: ''
      };
      break;
  };

  return toReturn;
};

let ans = {
  title: "Gesso:",
  categorical: "dfasdfasz",
  text: "",
  classe: "Conduta",
  type: 3
}

console.log(resposta(ans))
```

Comment: `text, 'something else',` is this a typo? Should be `text: 'something else'`. Otherwise, nothing weird in your code, it works as expected.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: looks like you didn't watch at your debugger before posting?

Comment: I am betting you have a string and not a number.

Comment: @raina77ow yeah it was just a typo

Comment: @epascarello I also console.logged the typeof(answer.type) and got number in all cases

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in this code?

Comment: Could you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(answer.type))` right inside that function, immediately before the switch? And yes, setting up a breakpoint would be even easier.

Comment: @raina77ow I console.logged what you asked and I get the number type printed for the object I pass into the function

Comment: @Barmar I added a code snippet and now it can be seen as I see it. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: `ans.categorical` and `ans.text` are both empty strings, so the result is the same as the default case.

Comment: @Barmar indeed, and when I change them to non-empty here in the snippet I get a differente result, so probably the problem is in the rest of my code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: other than that `answer.categorical` and `answer.text` are empty strings I don't see why it would return an object like the one in the default case. I couldn't recreate the problem...